# Android: верска элемента меню

Tags: xml, android, java, вёрстка

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка в верстке элемента меню? Задача: при очень длинном названии, скрывать его часть не переходя на другую строку. Она частично выполнена, но при выводе поглащает текствью который должен быть справа от текста.

[image: drawer navigation]

*У последнего пункта должна быть цифра 1, но она не выводиться из-за длины `text1`*

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/llMenu"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="9dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
    android:paddingBottom="9dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_item_text"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textColor="@color/menu_item_text_count_notifications"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Перепробовал разные варианты с шириной элемента `text1`, но успехом это не увенчалось.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Вместо android:layout_width="match_parent" попробуйте android:layout_width="wrap_content" у обоих TextView

Comment: @Suvitruf - попробовал, не работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У `android:id="@+id/text1"` поставить `android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать родителя LinearLayout, горизонтальной ориентации. Приведу пример кода:
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

```
    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/text2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```